# MYSQL ABS and GROUP By Function

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have sql code like this, when I execute the code without `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT CompanyName, TotalPremi
FROM (`tblPackage`)
INNER JOIN `tblCompany` ON `tblPackage`.`CompanyID` = `tblCompany`.`CompanyID`
WHERE `tblPackage`.`PackageType` =  '2'
AND `tblPackage`.`IsActive` =  '1'
ORDER BY abs(tblPackage.TotalPremi - 150000)
```

the result will be

CompanyName        |    TotalPremi
Generali | 150000 
Generali | 100000 
Generali | 200000 
Generali | 250000 
Verista  | 250000

How i can group by with CompanyName?
I have try with this code

```
SELECT CompanyName, TotalPremi
FROM (`tblPackage`)
INNER JOIN `tblCompany` ON `tblPackage`.`CompanyID` = `tblCompany`.`CompanyID`
WHERE `tblPackage`.`PackageType` =  '2'
AND `tblPackage`.`IsActive` =  '1'
GROUP BY CompanyName
ORDER BY abs(tblPackage.TotalPremi - 150000)
```

when i use this code, the `ABS` function is not working.

the result will be show

CompanyName        |    TotalPremi
Generali | 100000 
Verista  | 250000

**My Expected result like this**
CompanyName        |    TotalPremi
Generali | 150000 
Verista  | 250000

Comment: what is the expected result when you group by company?

Comment: I Want the result like this @NikhilBatra
CompanyName | TotalPremi
Generali | 150000
Verista | 250000

Comment: can you please throw some more light into this requirement of yours. Y do you want the 150000 one from Generali and ignore the other ones. Could you please explain the problem with a bit more detail. @RezhaVelly

Comment: I want to search data where `TotalPremi`  nearest by 160000` (*Dinamic) and then use function `GroupBy CompanyName` @AritraBhattacharya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use this SQL if you want to achieve the result you mentioned in your comment.

```
                SELECT CompanyName, TotalPremi
            FROM (`tblPackage`)
            INNER JOIN `tblCompany` ON `tblPackage`.`CompanyID` = `tblCompany`.`CompanyID`
            WHERE `tblPackage`.`PackageType` =  '2'
            AND `tblPackage`.`IsActive` =  '1'
            AND TotalPremi BETWEEN 140000 AND 170000
            GROUP BY CompanyName
            ORDER BY CompanyName, TotalPremi
            ;
```

Please let me know if this is okay.

Comment: Hi thank you for helping me with your method, now i follow your method to use Between :D